# Removing data from all highchart series

Tags: javascript, highcharts, series

Take the following simplified example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript'
  src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
            },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i']
            },          
        series: [
            {data: [20, 0, 100, 0.1, 150, 20, 30, 40, 300]},
            {data: [15, 0, 140, 1, 15, 5, 3, 4, 30]}
            ]
            },function(chart){
                chart.series[0].data[0].remove(false);
                chart.series[1].data[0].remove(false);
                chart.redraw();     
                        }
        );
    });     
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
  <div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

This works as intended and removes the first data points in both series, as well as the label.

HOWEVER, you'll notice the 2nd data value is 0 in both series and this is the one I want to remove both the data points and label for. If I change the code to:

```
chart.series[0].data[1].remove(false);
chart.series[1].data[1].remove(false);
```

This doesn't work as intended. How would I go about achieving that ... so essentially, if data points for all series are zero I need to remove that data and label and shift everything up ?

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to have no '0' value elements in your data? If so that would be better done on the backend where you generate the data.

Comment: I wish I had more control over the backend, but unfortunately I don't.

Comment: What you need to do is also remove the `categories` element at the index of the `series.data` you want to remove.

Comment: @wergeld. Thanks for the idea - do you have any example code ?

Comment: Took a while, but I found a solution. Here is an abbreviated version: `,function(chart){
    chart.series[0].data[1].remove(false);
    chart.series[1].data[1].remove(false);
    
    chart.xAxis[0].categories=['a','c','d','e','f','g','h','i']
    
    $.each(chart.series,function(sKey,sVal){
       $.each(sVal.data, function(k,v){
            v.update({x: k},false);
             }); 
             });
    chart.redraw(); 
      }`

Comment: that will work but only until such time as the data changes from your source.